# how to connect to sqlite build in database?

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

In Unity3d there are 2 ways to include files in build:
1. Expose a reference to an asset by declaring a member-variable, and then assign it in the inspector
2. Put assets in the "Resources" folders, and then load them by Resources.Load
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.html

I chosen second variant. myDB.bytes I load in TextAsset. 
TextAsset db = Resources.Load("myDB");

Now I want to connect to this database using sqlite API. But I can connect only to file using filename, or create new database in memory. How to use existing TextAsset instance to work with it as sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. You need to import the Data package.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/188334/unity-sql-database.html

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution.
Save TextAsset at Application.dataPath as database, and use file path.

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(Application.dataPath + "/db.bytes", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter binary = new BinaryWriter(fs);
binary.Write(dbTextAsset.bytes);
fs.Close();

sqlite3_open(Application.dataPath + "/db.bytes".....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the top search results provided by Google:

Place your database in the folder **Assets/StreamingAssets**.

Reference to it by using **Application.streamingAssetsPath**.

```
database_path = "URI=file:" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + database_name;
using (var connection = new SqliteConnection (database_path)) {
            connection.Open();
            //...
}
```

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

---

You also might want to take a look at https://ornithoptergames.com/how-to-set-up-sqlite-for-unity/ for information on how to access the database from your scripts.